# Use IFERROR and VLOOKUP only on filtered range/cells (dynamically formula/code)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a data set and I would like to filter in J column and use iferror and Vlookup formula. Where I have lookup value in G column and table array is in the other sheet(within workbook). Lookup value would not be constant in the same column, but sometimes it changes to I Column.

Currently, I have used the is code:

```
ReconWS.Range(Cells(2, Category), _
              Cells(ReconRows, Category)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Category!C[-38]:C[-37],2,0)"
```

Kindly guide/help in writing the dynamic code to use Iferror and Vlookup on a filtered range/cells along with the dynamic lookup value

Please Help!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what version of Excel are you using ?

Comment: Hi @Gary'sStudent, I'm using O365 Version: MSO(16.0.11929.20760) Build version 1908

Comment: FYI you should use `ReconWS.Cells` and not just `Cells` or you'll get an error if another sheet is active.

Comment: Sure @TimWilliams. Would you please help me with any solution for my query.

Comment: I'm not following what you want to do.  In what way is your lookup "dynamic" ?  It would help to provide some concrete examples.